# howto make diff look like svn diff?

Tags: svn, diff

I'm bad dumb and having no google fu.  How do you get diff (on os x if it matters...) to look like svn diffs?  Couldn't figure it out from the man page either. :(

What I want

```
Index: test.txt
===================================================================
--- test.txt (revision 365)
+++ test.txt (working copy)
@@ -1,7 +1,9 @@
 This
 is
 the
-original
+updated
+and
+awesomer
 file.

-Unf.
+Duh.
```

Comment: I had to look up Google Fu. +1!!

Answer (score 28):

You want the -u flag.

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

From the `diff` man page:

```
   -u  -U NUM  --unified[=NUM]
          Output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context.
```

It's not *exactly* the same (no big row of equals signs, for example), but it should do what you want.  Your example from above:

```
--- file1   2009-10-16 15:14:24.000000000 -0700
+++ file2   2009-10-16 15:14:50.000000000 -0700
@@ -1,7 +1,9 @@
 This
 is
 the
-original
+updated
+and
+awesomer
 file.

-Unf.
+Duh.
```

Answer (score 6):

subversion uses a slightly extended version of the unified diff format. Wikipedias page on [Diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) explains the format itself, and also notes the differences to the subversion ones.

As has been said, the diff tool (see its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) for details) uses the `-u` option to produce unified diffs.

Answer (score 5):

```
diff -u file1 file2
```